# What is --miner.noverify in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, command-line, cli

Here is a Geth command line option for miners:

```
--miner.noverify
```

The description in the [documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options) says that it "Disable remote sealing verification". But what does that mean? What is remote sealing in a mining context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remote Sealing Verification**

Remote Sealing Verification verifies if the block has a valid seal according to the POW (Proof-of-work) algorithm.

**Proof-of-work**

Proof-of-work is the underlying algorithm that sets the difficulty and rules for the work miners do. Mining is the "work" itself. It's the act of adding valid blocks to the chain. This is important because the chain's length helps the network spot the valid Ethereum chain and understand Ethereum's current state. The more "work" done, the longer the chain and the higher the block number, the more certain the network can be of the current state of things.

[Read more on ethereum.org](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pow/)

`--miner.noverify`

This option will simply disable the PoW workload verification.

Comment: Would the purpose of setting this to true would be to gain some performance, to the expense of less security?

Comment: If you are sure that your miners are creating valid blocks, you can set it to true and gain performance. It would not cause a security breach.